# Is it possible to visualize data with a large number of features (>50) in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a dataset with a large number of features. I need to understand my data before going further in the analysis. I have around 160 variables. After a little bit cleaning, I finished with only 60 features in my hand. I want to visualize my data hopefully to get a much more clear picture about it. How can I visualize data with 60 features in R?

Comment: Why not try running a PCA? I have a tutorial on the topic which may help here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pca-analysis-r

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You could just compile an html file with all the plots using [rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/).
The YAML header would be something like:

```
---
title: "HTML page with plots"
author: "YourAme"
date: "12/12/2018"
output: html_document
---
```

and then in the script you can create an R code block with the plots:

````
```{r}
plot(x1,y)
plot(x2,y)
plot(x60,y)
```
````

Finally, click the "knit" button.

Comment: Your moderation comments, while correct, probably don't belong in your answer, but rather in a comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for letting me notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your refined data set is in a data frame/matrix, you may look at the correlation matrix of all your input predictors:

```
res <- cor(your_data)
round(res, 2)
```

This would give at least a rough idea of what relationships might exist between the various predictors.

Note: I am assuming here that your actual ask centers around being able to see, at a glance, what your data set looks like, before you go and build some type of model.